# Automatically convert switch statements to if-else (Dart)

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

In my codebase multiple middleware files use `Switch` statements.
I need to convert all of these into `if else` statements.

I am hoping I don't have to do this change manually as this could introduce bugs. I am looking for any editor or plugin that supports this conversion for Dart code.

In my current editor, Intellij, I saw an intention for this conversion but it did not seem to support Dart.

Any editor or plugin suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Dart intentions/refactorings are powered by the Dart Analysis Server, a tool from the Dart SDK. Please file a request for this feature to [SDK issues tracker](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues)